# How to manage multiple simulations that continually create large datasets

Tags: numerical-methods

my work is related to mathematical modelling and running computer simulations in fluid mechanics. I have a mathematical model that has, say, has 5 parameters. Each of them have some range defined by us, and we would like to study how this model performs within these ranges.

We make a computer code, and start running simulations.

1. Very soon, I have an extremely large dataset, and it becomes increasingly difficult to keep track of what simulation i run when...
2. ...and if they are running on different computers, it is even more difficult to manage.
3. One simulation takes about 3-4 days to finish, so by the time one finishes, we have to track our lab notes to see what made us run that simulation in the first place.
4. The problem is compounded when the number of parameters is very large, obviously.

I want something that tracks all of this. An app, website, tool, code, software, anything that can tabulate all of these parameters. Maybe record dates, keep track of re-runs, and just show the 'status-board' of all my simulations.

Comment: Having a large dataset does not make much sense if you don't have compact "evaluation" criteria that helps you understand the behavior. And if a single simulation lasts for days and you have 5 parameters, the situation seems hopeless. What exactly do you want to look at ?

Comment: Start by writing HDF5 files, then add metadata that allows you to track provenance of those files. It's hard work. If you put the timestamp and a short description in your .h5, it'll go a long way to remembering why you started a job.